# onScroll event in Mobi PDFViewerSDK

Tags: android, pdf, sdk

I’m using MOBI PDFViewer SDK (http://www.androidpdf.mobi/)  and I faced a problem: PDFReader class have not onScroll event .
I found a lot of methods: onSingleTap, onDoubleTap and many others, but there is no onScroll.

How I can implement this method?

Comment: Please edit your question and form it using at least simple English, because in this state it's completely not understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check Motion event and create method or listner. Open PDFReader class and write in onTouchEvent method.

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (m_view == null)
            return false;
        if (m_view.vGetLock() == 3) {
            if (onTouchInk(event))
                return true;
            if (onTouchRect(event))
                return true;
            if (onTouchEllipse(event))
                return true;
            if (onTouchNote(event))
                return true;
            if (onTouchLine(event))
                return true;
            if (onTouchAnnot(event))
                return true;
        }


        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
             //paste here your action
        }

        return m_view.vTouchEvent(event);
    }
```